# terragrunt plan failing with timeout while waiting for plugin to start

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terragrunt

I have ran terragrunt init and it went successfully & downloaded required providers but while running terragrunt plan it hung with below errors and crashes my computer. While I'm trying to update an IAM role getting this error.

terragrunt plan

Error: Could not load plugin

Plugin reinitialization required. Please run "terraform init".

Plugins are external binaries that Terraform uses to access and manipulate
resources. The configuration provided requires plugins which can't be
located,
don't satisfy the version constraints, or are otherwise incompatible.

Terraform automatically discovers provider requirements from your
configuration, including providers used in child modules. To see the
requirements and constraints, run "terraform providers".

2 problems:

- failed to instantiate provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws" to
  obtain schema: timeout while waiting for plugin to start
- failed to instantiate provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/vault" to
  obtain schema: timeout while waiting for plugin to start